# ROS Answers SE migration: hokuyo node

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed hokuyo driver on hydro usin
sudo apt-get intall ros-hydro-urg-node

When I type in rosrun urg_node urg_node
I get the error: Unknown error connecting to Hokuyo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172599/hokuyo-node/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-02**:
I don't know how urg_node works, but I'm sure the information of what hokuyo you connect how to which system will be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hokuyo 04lx
And sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hokuyo-node works!

---

Originally posted by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) with karma: 120 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0